# Site wide timer

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using `vaadin` as a framework for our application. I  want to implement a timer on the server that would periodically fire an event but I want it to be a  System-wide Polling thread, so that there is only one running on the server and all `UI`'s use that timer if needed. I realise that if it is in the `UI` then a new thread is created with each `UI` instance. So I'm not sure where to put it. In the class that extends `Vaadin Servlet`, as in in the `servletInitialized` method? If so not sure how to get the event out of there into a class that can use it.

Wanting to do something like this

```
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try 
            {
                System.out.println("fired event");
                //get the event out of here to somewhere in the code that can use it
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        }
    };
    Timer t = new Timer(true);
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 10000);
}
```

}

but wanting to run it somewhere where it will get started at app startup not in each instance that is fired up

Comment: Kindly provide what you have tried so far i.e. your codes so we may be able to assist your further. Thank you.

Comment: Thx Keith. I've just decided to use the pollListener event in the UI to fire off events on a polled interval. Seems to work ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code in a globally accessible place that your UI components can register to receive the tick events

```
interface GlobalTimerListener {
    void onTick();
}
class GlobalTimer {
    private static List<GlobalTimerListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void register(GlobalTimerListener gtl) {
        listeners.add(gtl);
    }
    static {
        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("fired event");
                    //get the event out of here to somewhere in the code that can use it
                    for (GlobalTimerListener listener : listeners) {
                        listener.onTick();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        Timer t = new Timer(true);
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 10000);
    }
}
```

Then in your UI you can act on the events by registering to receive them. The onTick method will be called whenever the timer task is executed.

```
class ElseWhereInTheUI {
    public ElseWhereInTheUI() {
        GlobalTimer.register(new GlobalTimerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTick() {
                doTheThingThatHappensOnTick();
            }
        });
    }
    private void doTheThingThatHappensOnTick() {
        //...
    }
}
```